# How does one define a representation in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

It seems that the [reference manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap0.html) for GAP never mentions how to construct a representation by sending generators to specified matrices. Yet I cannot help but feel that such a basic task must be achievable. How does one do it?

As a concrete example, I want to consider the $5$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_3$-representation $\rho$ of $C_8$ sending a generator $g$ to
$$ \rho(g) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$
How do I feed this representation to GAP?

**Edit.** Thanks to Olexandr Konovalov and Derek Holt, I got the following to work:

```
G := CyclicGroup(8);
gen := GeneratorsOfGroup(G)[1];
GLn := GeneralLinearGroup(5, GF(3));
img := Z(3)^0 * [[1, 0, 1, 2, 2], 
        [2, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
        [1, 0, 2, 1, 0], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
        [2, 1, 1, 0, 2]];
rep := GroupHomomorphismByImages(G, GLn, [gen], [img]);
```

However, I'm still a bit confused about how to feed the resulting representation into the functions that are of relevance to representation theory. I've asked a follow-up question on this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449522/how-to-make-gap-understand-that-a-homomorphism-is-a-representation).

**Edit 2.** It turns out that `GeneralLinearGroup()` is a function that works only works for finite fields. It works for the example that I gave for the purpose of being concrete, but of course I look for an answer that captures representations over a general base. As such, **this question is still unsolved**.

Comment: A representation is a homomorphism - please see https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap40.html how to construct them.

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov Thanks, I've used the suggestion to make an attempt but I cannot get it to work. I will share the attempt in the question now.

Comment: The entries in your target matrix are integers, but they are suppose to be elements of the field of order $3$. You can achieve that easily by multiplying the whole matrix by Z(3)^0, as in Z(3)^0*[[1,2],[0,1]].

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the suggestion, that was indeed what I was currently trying to fix. However, it still seems that I cannot get it to work. I have defined ```x := Z(3)``` and fed it the matrix where ```1``` and ```2``` are replaced by ```x^2``` and ```x```, respectively, but it throws me the same error.

Comment: You also need to replace 0 by 0*Z(3). As I said in my previous comment, the easiest solution is to multiply the whole matrix by Z(3)^0.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks! But I'm still a bit confused. I have now constructed the representation as a homomorphism. How can I make GAP understand that I wish to analyse it as a representation. For instance, let's say I want to know the decomposition of this representation using ```MTX.Indecomposables()```. This doesn't seem to work, and though the error is obscure, I suspect that such a function requires a different data type as its input.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking new questions in comments.

Comment: @DerekHolt Alright then. I can move it to a separate question.