# Induced representations in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

**Background.**

In [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448876/how-does-one-define-a-representation-in-gap) I asked how one defines a (modular!) representation in GAP, and I came to learn that one just has to provide GAP with the entire group homomorphism using `GroupHomomorphismByImages`.

Some representation-theoretic functions turn out to expect you to give the representation in a different form. For instance, in [a follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449522/how-to-make-gap-understand-that-a-homomorphism-is-a-representation) I asked how to apply a MeatAxe-based function to my homomorphism (assuming my representation is over $\mathbb{F}_p$), and I came to learn that, actually, you had to implement it differently, namely using `GModuleByMats`.

This question is yet another instance of such a confusion.

**Question.**

I have a subgroup $H$ of a (finite) group $G$, and I have an explicit $H$-representation (preferably over a *general* base field). I would like GAP to give me the induced $G$-representation. What's the right way to go about this?

**What I tried.**

[Chapter 2 of the manual of the GAP package `repsn`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/repsn/doc/chap2.html) suggests that my task is possible. It lists a function called `InducedSubgroupRepresentation` which claims to do what we want. But there are two issues.

- No such function actually seems to exist. However, there's a function called `InducedRepresentation`. I will just assume that that's what the manual means.
- The manual is vague about the type of input. It claims it wants an ambient group $G$ and a representation. But as I now know, to GAP, 'representation' can mean many things. I have tried both the type produced by `GroupHomomorphismByImages` and by `GModuleByMats`. Neither of them work. Presumably, there's a third, yet different, way of implementing representations. What's the right implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ahulpke --- that already answers the question why I couldn't find the ```InducedSubgroupRepresentation``` function --- additionally, looking at the ```repsn``` package, I find that it is aimed at representations in characteristic $0$ (which is not what I'm looking at right now). So I need some different method to get what I want.

Comment: your best bet in these cases is to read the source, which is [here](https://github.com/gap-packages/repsn/blob/master/gap/repsn.g). In particular, it *does* define an `InducedSubgroupRepresentation` function, suggesting there's a problem with your installation of the `respn` package.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Thanks for the suggestion --- that was a mistake on my part. I was unaware that this function depended on a package. (The layout of its manual is identical to that of GAP so I was under the impression that I was reading the GAP manual.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this is (now corrected) not a function in main GAP, but in the package `repsn`. If we look at the documentation, we find an example that shows that the second argument is a homomorphism. However, when trying it for a representation in characteristic non-zero, an error arises

```
gap> g:=SymmetricGroup(5);;
gap> h:=SymmetricGroup(3);;
gap> reps:=IrreducibleRepresentations(h,GF(5));
[ [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ [ [ Z(5)^0 ] ], [ [ Z(5)^0 ] ] ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ [ [ Z(5)^0 ] ], [ [ Z(5)^2 ] ] ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ [ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ], [ Z(5)^2, Z(5)^2 ] ],
      [ [ Z(5)^2, Z(5)^2 ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ] ] ]
gap> InducedSubgroupRepresentation(g,reps[2]);
Error, usage: Group(<gen>,...), Group(<gens>), Group(<gens>,<id>) at /Users/hulpke/gap4/lib/grp.gi:4764 called from
Group( l ) at /Users/hulpke/gap4/pkg/repsn-3.1.0/gap/repsn.g:341 called
```

We inspect the error causing argument

```
brk> l;
[ [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Z(5)^0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[...]
```

and see (combination of rational 0 and characteristic five: Z(5)^0) that the error is due to careless coding for characteristic zero.
This makes the function easy to fix. Lets look at the code:

```
gap> Print(InducedSubgroupRepresentation);
function ( G, rep )
   [...]
    nmat := NullMat( d, d );
   [...]
```

We need to make this null matrix over the right field, so replace this line with:

```
    nmat := NullMat( d, d, DefaultFieldOfMatrixGroup(Range(rep)) );
```

Also, it would be good to use compact matrices, the resulting code is below (and does not need the repsn package any longer). With this, it also works in finite characteristic:

```
gap> NewInducedRepresentation(g,reps[2]);
[ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2) ] -> [ < immutable compressed matrix 20x20 over GF(5) >,
  < immutable compressed matrix 20x20 over GF(5) > ]
```

--- Code follows for your convenience ---

```
NewInducedRepresentation:=function ( G, rep )
local F,M, M1, mat, u, U, rt, i, j, k, LL, L, m, Ls, Lr, l, d, h, r, t,
    nmat, lrt;
    mat := [  ];
    L := [  ];
    h := PreImagesRange( rep );
    if Size( h ) = 1 then
        d := 1;
    else
        d := DimensionsMat( GeneratorsOfGroup( Image( rep ) )[1] )[1];
    fi;
    F:=DefaultFieldOfMatrixGroup(Range(rep));
    U := GeneratorsOfGroup( G );
    rt := RightTransversal( G, h );
    lrt := Length( rt );
    nmat := NullMat( d, d, F );
    for u in U do
        M := [  ];
        for i in [ 1 .. lrt ] do
            t := rt[i] * u;
            M1 := [  ];
            for j in [ 1 .. lrt ] do
                r := t * rt[j] ^ -1;
                if r in h then
                    Add( M1, r ^ rep );
                else
                    Add( M1, nmat );
                fi;
            od;
            Add( M, M1 );
        od;
        Add( mat, M );
    od;
    for m in mat do
        LL := [  ];
        Lr := [  ];
        Ls := [  ];
        for i in [ 1 .. lrt ] do
            for j in [ 1 .. d ] do
                for k in [ 1 .. lrt ] do
                    Add( LL, m[i][k][j] );
                od;
                Add( Ls, Concatenation( LL ) );
                LL := [  ];
            od;
            Add( Lr, Ls );
        od;
        Add( L, Lr );
    od;
    l := List( L,i->ImmutableMatrix(F,i[1]));
    return GroupHomomorphismByImagesNC( G, Group( l ), U, l );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great insights. (In the defense of the ```Repsn``` makers,  the package did indicate that it is meant for characteristic-zero computations --- but I wasn't aware of that when asking the question.)